# Databinding Property not found, why?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

pls help me, why this binding doesn't works, I would like to binding from the PlayerBar.xaml which datacontext is PlayerBarPresenter to PlayerBarPresenter.Card1.ImgCard like this Source = Binding{Source Card1, Path = ImgCard} than I get this exception

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression
>   path error: 'ImgCard' property not found on 'Card1' 'System.String'
>   (HashCode=949723141). BindingExpression: Path='ImgCard'
>   DataItem='Card1' (HashCode=949723141); target element is
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source'
>   (type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource')..

the file is found If is biding in the same property just in the TablePresenter, but I want to binding in the TablePresenter.Card1.ImgCard

UserControl x:Class="poki.View.PlayerBar" Data context is TablePresenter

```
    <Image Width="50" Height="80" Source="{Binding Source=Card1, Path=ImgCard}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Canvas.Left="108.358"
Canvas.Top="-8.349">
```

TablePresenter.cs

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using poki.View;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using poki.Model;

namespace poki.Presenters
{
    public class PlayerBarPresenter : PresenterBase<PlayerBar>
    {

        private BitmapImage playerImage;
        public BitmapImage PlayerImage
        {
            get { return playerImage; }
            set
            {
                playerImage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PlayerImage");
            }
        }

        private Card card1;
        public Card Card1
        {
            get { return card1; }
            set
            {
                card1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Card1");
            }
        }



#endregion


        public PlayerBarPresenter(PlayerBar pb) : base(pb)
        {
            Card1 = new Card(22);

            Card1.S = "fasyom";           
        }
    }
}
```

table.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using poki.Presenters;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using poki.Model;

namespace poki.View
{
    public partial class Table : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public TablePresenter Presenter { get { return this.DataContext as TablePresenter; } }

        public Table()
        {
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Table_Loaded);
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Table_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext = new TablePresenter(this); 

            PlayerBarPresenter a = new PlayerBarPresenter(new PlayerBar());


            //a.Card1.ImgCard = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Datas/Images/1/7.png", UriKind.Relative));
            //a.Card2 = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Datas/Images/1/7.png",UriKind.Relative));
            gridTable.Children.Add(a.View);
        }




    }
}
```

card.cs

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace poki.Model
{
    public class Card : Notifier
    {
        public int card { get; set; }

        public Card(int Card1)
        {
            card = Card1;
            ImgCard = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Datas/Images/1/7.png", UriKind.Relative)); //new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Datas/Images/Cards/" + Suit + "/" + Rank + ".png",UriKind.Relative)); 

        }        

        public int Suit
        {
            get { return card / 13; }
        }

        public int Rank
        {
            get { return card % 13; }
        }


        private BitmapImage imgCard;
        public BitmapImage ImgCard
        {
            get { return imgCard; }
            set
            {
                imgCard = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ImgCard");
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the docs of a property before randomly setting it, i seems like you never looked at how the `Binding.Source` can be used.

Answer (score 5):

Think your binding expression is wrong, please try it like this:

```
<Image Width="50" Height="80" Source="{Binding Card1.ImgCard}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Canvas.Left="108.358" Canvas.Top="-8.349">
```

Comment: Great; please, don't forget to mark the question as "Answered"!

Answer (score 0):

You set the `Source` to the string `"Card1"`, of course it does not have any properties that you expect. As the card is in the `DataContext` you will want to extend the `Path` (`Path=Card1.ImgCard`), never set any source when binding to the `DataContext` or that will be used instead of the `DataContext`.